# "before I oops do it again" or "before I oops did it again again", which one should I have used for it to be proper English?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, expressions, phrase-usage, expression-choice

Last night my cousin was playing Britney Spears' "Oops I did it again" song, and then in the middle of the song I felt the need to use the rest room and then I wanted to tell him "I better hit the toilet before I oops do it again" but when I was going about doing my business in the restroom, I was thinking "did I use the proper English?"

What should I have said there for it to be proper English? I mean usually it might have conveyed the meaning and it would have been understood and funny a bit, but I am looking for grammatically correct English here.

Thank you.
And sorry if this question and its context might seem a bit disrespectful or disturbing to some folks.

Comment: It's absolutely not proper English, but given the song, I think most native English speakers would say "before I oops do it again" here.

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor

Comment: Why would it be disturbing?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I thought that maybe a song about love and stuff like that by Britney and comparing it to using the restroom might be something that some people might find offensive or disturbing. I really meant it to be funny.

Comment: Given the song and artist, a toilet joke is absolutely the best thing

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well respect is a mutual thing. I am not sure I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Oops!* or *whoops!* is just an exclamation you make when you fall or knock something over, or to acknowledge that you have made a mistake. So putting it in the middle of a sentence as you did doesn't really work, but of course your cousin would understand that you were imitating the words of the song. You could have said

*... before - oops! - I do it again.*

Comment: I see, so I needed to move I after oops, I see. Thank you Kate.